# Gdb on OSX 10.9 (64 bit) throws up a wall of text when I run a program

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, program-entry-point

Here is the whole sequence of commands and the wall of text:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000100000f20 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000f21 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000f24 <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000f28 <main+8>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f2f <main+15>:   movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f36 <main+22>:   cmpl   $0xa,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f3d <main+29>:   jge    0x100000f64 <main+68>
0x0000000100000f43 <main+35>:   lea    0x44(%rip),%rdi        # 0x100000f8e
0x0000000100000f4a <main+42>:   mov    $0x0,%al
0x0000000100000f4c <main+44>:   callq  0x100000f6e <dyld_stub_printf>
0x0000000100000f51 <main+49>:   mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f54 <main+52>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f57 <main+55>:   add    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000100000f5c <main+60>:   mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100000f5f <main+63>:   jmpq   0x100000f36 <main+22>
0x0000000100000f64 <main+68>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000100000f67 <main+71>:   add    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000100000f6b <main+75>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000100000f6c <main+76>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f2f: file firstprog.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/sankarshanmudkavi/Desktop/test/test/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +..............bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_bzero" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memccpy" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memchr" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memcmp" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memcpy" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memmove" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_memset" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_strchr" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_strcmp" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol "_strncmp" is unsupported 'indirect' reference: setting to undefined
....warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.1.72~6/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/_libc_funcptr.o" - no debug information available for "_libc_funcptr.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.1.72~6/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlen.o" - no debug information available for "strlen.c".
```

And more warnings of a similar sort. So what's going on exactly?
Googling around gave me nothing, but I suspect it has something to do with the architecture of my mac. (2012 rMBP).

Comment: Could be related to the reason xCode no longer supports gdb

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Could you provide a link please? I've got quite the same issue on my side

Comment: Bottom of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html